# Can't get background image in CSS to behave responsive , whitespace on bottom

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a background image which I want to set to fit the width of the browser window. If the height is bigger than the viewport, scrolling should enable one to see the whole image.

This is the solution I came up with that's closest to that:

```
body,html {

    margin: 0;

}

.image {
    background-image: url("Background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 227vh;
}
```

227vh is the height necessary to be able to scroll down and see the whole image on my 4k monitor. If I half the window size, you can see the whole picture but since the height is 227vh, you can further continue to scroll and whitespace covers the bottom of the page.

How can I crop this whitespace? The necessary vh for half the screen would be 110, those are factors 2.27 for the full screen and 1.1 for the half screen. How can I figure out the factors for each window size so that the image is always fit to the width of the window, the window is scrollable to see the whole background, and there is no whitespace left on the bottom?

I tried all kinds of different settings.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can't you use `object-fit:cover`?

Comment: What is the pixel width of the image? You can use javascript to get the pixel width of the window and calculate the width and height of the container that has the background.